# How can I group data in Delphi

Tags: delphi, grouping, tdbgrid

I have a problem in a Delphi 11. How can i group data in a TDBGridEh like that (with pluses)
[image: Screenshot with grouping]

I try use DataGrouping, but nothing happens, even hide rows.
[image: Screenshot without grouping]

Comment: You may try https://forum.ehlib.com/en/viewforum.php?f=5